# How many times are Liferay theme velocity templates executed?

Tags: java, liferay, velocity

Are all `vm` files of the theme executed each time a page is requested? Maybe `custom_init.vm` is executed only once per session or some other optimizations occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution happens on every pageview. It obviously has to, as it can contain conditionals, like `#if($is_signed_in)` that will generate different output depending on the condition on every single page rendering.

This is true for all *.vm files - they just include init.vm and custom_init.vm, but even the initialization in these files can depend on runtime conditions.